# Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, веб-программирование

Очень прошу о помощи! Делаю сайт, сделал регистрацию и вход, вроде все работало, но потом что-то, видимо, случайно изменил и теперь выдается ошибка "OSError: [WinError 123] Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома: ''"
Если порыться в консоли выше, где идет перебор всех файлов, то можно найти строку ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'first.apps.FirstConfig'; 'first.apps' is not a package. Вероятно в ней и проблема, но самостоятельно у меня ее найти не выходит.
Далее предоставлю файлы и расположение папок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
URLS(ОБЩИЙ)

```
import first
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('first.urls')),
    path('rule', include('first.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),  # grappelli URLS
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS)
```

URLS(ЛОКАЛЬНЫЙ)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
import first
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
urlpatterns = [
    path('reg', views.index, name='index'),
    path('rule', views.poop, name='poop'),
    path('register/', views.RegisterFormView.as_view()),
    path('login/', views.LoginFormView.as_view()),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    #url(r'^register/$', views.RegisterFormView.as_view()),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS)
```

VIEWS

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import first
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
# Опять же, спасибо django за готовую форму аутентификации.
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

# Функция для установки сессионного ключа.
# По нему django будет определять, выполнил ли вход пользователь.
from django.contrib.auth import login

class LoginFormView(FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm

    # Аналогично регистрации, только используем шаблон аутентификации.
    template_name = "first/login.html"

    # В случае успеха перенаправим на главную.
    success_url = "/about"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Получаем объект пользователя на основе введённых в форму данных.
        self.user = form.get_user()

        # Выполняем аутентификацию пользователя.
        login(self.request, self.user)
        return super(LoginFormView, self).form_valid(form)  

class RegisterFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    # Ссылка, на которую будет перенаправляться пользователь в случае успешной регистрации.
    # В данном случае указана ссылка на страницу входа для зарегистрированных пользователей.
    success_url = "/login"

    # Шаблон, который будет использоваться при отображении представления.
    template_name = "first/registration.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Создаём пользователя, если данные в форму были введены корректно.
        form.save()

        # Вызываем метод базового класса
        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)


def poop(request):
    return render(request, 'first/rules.html')


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'first/registration.html')


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'first/about.html')
```

SETTINGS
    import first
    import os
    import sys

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'first.apps.FirstConfig',

]
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'universal.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'universal.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    'universal/static',
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оказалось, что файл apps.py был очищен каким-то образом
Вот, что туда вписал:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class FirstConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'first'
```

Теперь все работает